# Is this metric space complete?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, banach-spaces

Let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a < b$, and let $X$ be the metric space of all the (real- or complex-valued) functions defined and continuous on the closed interval $[a,b]$ with the metric $d$ defined as follows: 
$$d(x,y) \colon= \ \int_a^b \ \vert x(t) - y(t) \vert \ \mathrm{d} t \ \mbox{ for all } \ x, y \in X.$$

Then is $X$ complete?

Let $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $(X,d)$. Then, given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a natural number $N$ such that 
$$d(x_m, x_n) < \epsilon \ \mbox{ for all } \ m, n \in \mathbb{N} \ \mbox{ such that} \ m > N \ \mbox{ and } \ n > N. $$
That is, 
$$\int_a^b \ \vert x_m(t) - x_n(t) \vert \ \mathrm{d} t < \epsilon \ \mbox{ for all } \ m, n \in \mathbb{N} \ \mbox{ such that} \ m > N \ \mbox{ and } \ n > N. $$
What next?

Comment: Of course don't hurry, but if one of the answers is okay then be so kind to accept it. I have noticed that your rate of acceptance is very low.

Comment: Thanks for all of you have answered my query or have commented on those answers or on my original question. But can anyone here please also post an answer (i) with general $a$ and $b$,  (ii) showing clearly how their proposed sequence is Cauchy (and what motivated them to come up with their choice for that sequence), and (iii) also show directly why this sequence fails to converge in this metric. I feel the answers already posted are referring to some fact(s) without actually citing those result, thus making it slightly hard to fully grasp the proofs.

Answer (score 2):

The ultimate answer to the question is "no". One must be careful in proving this, because it is possible to furnish a function which converges in your metric to a discontinuous function *and* to a continuous function. The problem here is that when you enlarge the domain to include certain discontinuous functions, the resulting metric becomes a pseudometric, so its limits are not unique. For instance this occurs with the example of $f_n(x)=x^n$ on $[0,1]$. This appears to converge to the pointwise limit, which has a jump at $1$, but it *also* converges in this metric to the zero function, which is continuous. Thus this sequence does not help us to prove that this space is not complete.

We should instead consider approximating a function with a jump in the *interior* of the domain. For instance consider the sequence

$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases} 0 & x \in [0,1/2-1/n] \\ n(x-1/2+1/n)/2 & x \in [1/2-1/n,1/2+1/n] \\ 1 & x \in [1/2+1/n,1] \end{cases}$$

for $n=2,3,\dots$. These rise linearly from $0$ to $1$ very rapidly close to $1/2$. (It is much easier to graph these than it is to write down a formula.) In the pointwise limit there is a jump at $1/2$. You should argue that if $f_n \to f$ in your metric then $f$ cannot be continuous at $1/2$.

Comment: you might wanna elaborate on why it is not possible for the sequence $f_n$ to converge to a continuous function. Also, could you please give a (detailed) proof for a \textit{general} closed interval $[a,b]$, where $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a<b$?

Comment: can you please also show that your sequence $f_n$ is indeed Cauchy?

Comment: A general closed interval can be managed by just composing the example above with a linear map from one interval to another. The Cauchiness in my example is pretty straightforward: take $n<m$, then $f_n$ and $f_m$ are bounded in absolute value by $1$ and they agree except on a set of measure $2/n$. So their difference in the metric from the OP is less than $4/n$.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud As for showing that $f_n$ cannot converge to a continuous function, you can use the reverse triangle inequality to argue that the distance between $f_n$ and any given continuous function $g$ is bounded below by $d(f,g)-d(f_n,f)$, where $f$ is the pointwise limit. Now $d(f,g)$ is *positive* (this is crucial, and not obvious), while $d(f_n,f)$ can be made arbitrarily small.

Answer (score 1):

No, consider $[a,b]=[0,1]$ and

$$y_n(t)= \begin{cases} 0 & 0\le t\le {1\over 2}-{1\over n+1} \\
{n+1\over 2}(x-{1\over 2}+{1\over n+1})& {1\over 2}-{1\over n+1}\le t\le {1\over 2}+{1\over n+1}\\
1 & {1\over 2}+{1\over n+1}\le t\le 1\end{cases}$$

Then each $y_n$ is continuous is clear. The limit in the completion (which may be our original set or not, that's what we're investigating) has a point-wise representative

$$y(t) =\begin{cases} 0 & 0\le t < {1\over 2} \\ {1\over 2} & t={1\over 2} \\ 1 & {1\over 2}<t\le 1\end{cases}.$$

If there is a continuous representative, $y_0(t)$ then we note that $y_0(t)$ has the property that ${1\over \epsilon}\int_{1/2}^{1/2+\epsilon}y(t)\,dt\to y(1/2)=1/2$ by the FTC. However, it is clear that that integral is identically $1$ for all $\epsilon$, hence no such $y_0$ exists.

The big picture:  continuous functions have a nice averaging property in integration. By finding a function which is the pointwise limit we are able to figure out what averages (i.e. integration) properties a candidate limit would have. But since we know we can mess with the average around the discontinuity, we see a way forward to construct a counter-example.

Answer (score 1):

The metric is not complete.

Say $[a.b]=[0,2]$. Say $y_n(t)=t^n$ for $0\le t\le 1$ and $y_n(t)=1$ for $1\le t\le 2$. Then $(y_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence. But it is not convergent in our metric.

*Showing* that it's not convergent is trickier than you might think. Define $y(t)=\lim y_n(t)$. Then $y(t)=0$ for $0\le t < 1$ while $y(t)=1$ for $1\le t\le 2$. So $y$ is not continuous. But that's not a proof. It's really *not* a proof; if that were a proof then a certain *wrong* example would be right. See below for the wrong example.

First show this: If $f$ is continuous then $$\epsilon=\int_0^2|f(t)-y(t)|\,dt>0.$$ Now choose $N$ so $$\int_0^2|y_n-y|<\epsilon/2\quad(n>N).$$ It follows that if $n>N$ then $$d(f,y_n)=\int_0^2|f-y_n|\ge\int_0^2|f-y|-\int_0^2|y-y_n|>\epsilon-\epsilon/2=\epsilon/2.$$So $d(f,y_n)$ does not tend to zero.

**Wrong Example:** Say $[a,b]=[0,1]$, and let $y_n(t)=t^n$. As before let $y(t)=\lim y_n(t)$. Then $y$ is not continuous. But that's irrelevant, because the *pointwise* limit is irrelevant; what matters is the limit *in* the metric $d$. If we let $x(t)=0$ for all $t$ then in fact $d(y_n,x)\to0$. So *this* sequence *is* convergent in our metric space, even though the pointwise limit is discontinuous.

Comment: This answer is correct, but I don't think criticising other answers *within an answer* is the right thing to do. Otherwise, I would upvote this.

Comment: @tomasz You may have a point. Especially when the other answer has disappeared. See revised version.

Comment: @tomasz ??? Still have problems with the new version?

Comment: Yeah, that's better. (I wasn't the one to downvote, though.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich how do we show the following? If $f$ is continuous then $$\epsilon=\int_0^2|f(t)-y(t)|\,dt>0.$$ Moreover, how do we show that your sequence $y_n$ is indeed Cauchy. Could you please edit your answer to address these two issues?

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud Suppose $f$ is continuous and $\int_0^2|f-y|=0$. Then $\int_0^1|f-y|=0$. What does that tell you about $f$? Also $\int_1^2|f-y|=0$. What does that tell you about $f$? You show that $(y_n)$ is Cauchy from the definition.